# How to get source code of running Fedora linux?

Tags: fedora

This is the first time I am working on Fedora. I will be writing some device drivers.

I understand that for proper compilation of the driver I must have the same source code as that of the running kernel.

In Ubuntu I used to do this using `apt-get`. But this is not working in Fedora, so how do I download this?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't downloading the kernel source [directly](https://www.kernel.org/), and compiling that? You can checkout the specific version, and use the Fedora specific config file from your `/boot` directory.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel ... Haven't tried that, found via Google for *fedora kernel source*, first result.

Answer (score 5):

To download the source for the Linux kernel on a Red Hat based distro you'll need to use the tool `yum`. This is equivalent to `apt-get`. This tool needs to either be run using `sudo` or to become the root user on the box.

```
$ yum install kernel-devel kernel-tools kernel-headers
```

The source will be installed here:

```
$ ls -l /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)
```

Where `uname -r` is the version of the kernel + architecture that you're using:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.9-100.fc19.x86_64
```

This is the source for kernel version 3.13.9. The point release (the Fedora project adds patches to their kernel) which is represented by the `-100`. The architecture is `x86_64`, i.e. 64-bit.